# Old times or old time?

Tags: phrases

Which one is correct? If none of them are, could you be so kind as to provide a correct alternative?

> This song reminds me of the old times.

or

> This song reminds me of the old time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first sentence you wrote is the correct one.

As reported from the NOAD, *Old times* is used, for example, in the phrase *for old times' shake* to mean *in memory of former times, in acknowledgment of a shared past*.

> They sat in the back seats for old times' sake.

*Old-time* is used to refer to something old-fashioned in an approving or nostalgic way (*old-time dancing*).

Comment: It's usually just "old times", not "the old times"; so lose the "the" too, I'd say.